# Laravel delete record of table after the next day of expiry date?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Coupon::where('expire_date','<',Carbon::tomorrow())->delete(); 
// OR
Coupon::where('expire_date','<',Carbon::yesterday())->delete();
```

Comment: can you explain more what you want?

Comment: eg.. I create a discount coupon .it will be expire in 2023-2-10 23:59 .and I want to auto delete that coupon in 2023-2-11 23:59 from my database

Comment: Sorry I'm new user and not good in English .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the coupons where the expiry date (+1 day) is less than today, you can to it with a raw query.

It's your choice if you want to use `Carbon::today()` (time will always be 00:00:00) or `Carbon::now()` for this.

```php
Coupon::where(DB::raw('expire_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY'), '<', Carbon::now())->delete();
```

You could also move this logic into a query scope in the Coupon model.

```php
# Coupon.php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

public function scopeExpired(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->where(DB::raw('expire_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY'), '<', Carbon::now());
}
```

```php
Coupon::expired()->delete();
```

---

If you want this to happen automatically, you will need to set it up in the [Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#main-content).

```php
# app/Console/Kernel.php

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(fn() => Coupon::expired()->delete())->daily();
}
```

For the scheduler to run on its own, you need to add the following entry to your server's crontabs

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I create a discount coupon .it will be expire in 2023-2-10 23:59 .and I want to auto delete that coupon at 2023-2-11 23:59 from my database

Comment: You can use the scheduler for that.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow

Comment: protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(fn() => Coupon::where('expire_date','<',Carbon::now())->delete())->dailyAt('13:00')->timezone('Asia/Yangon');
    }
is it correct syntax ? i cannot run schedule . when i try php artisan schedule:run it said   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run. but it show 1 schedule when i type php artisan schedule:list .

Comment: You need to use the cron, not run `php artisan schedule:run` manually. Your server will run the scheduler using that cron.

Comment: class daily extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'daily:corn';

    protected $description = 'This will clean the db table';
    
    public function handle()
    {
        Coupon::where('expire_date','<',Carbon::now())->delete();
    }
} class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $daily = [Commands\daily::class];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('daily:corn')->dailyAt('11:42')->timezone('Asia/Yangon');
    }